# Excel Microsoft Query function to retrieve user name

Tags: sql, excel, microsoft-query

I have created microsoft query data connection which links to another spreadheet. In my sql query I need to filter out the lines that does not bellong to that user. To do so i am using where clouse and i need to compare the field to the current username. I have tried USER(), system.user(), current_user, system_user ... Nothing seems to work.

Also, anyone knows what language does microsoft query use? Is it a language on its own?

Comment: What language are you writing this in? vba?

Comment: Well that is the problem, i do not know what language excel is usung in the data connection sql query. Some mysql commands work, but not the user function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you

```
Environ("USERNAME")
```

This should return username at least in VBA